# python: iterating every combination of dictionary that contains lists as value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a dictionary which is dictList = {1:[1,3,4,8], 2:[5,7,2,8], 3:[6,3,5,7]}

I want to print all the combinations like this:
key,value
first iteration
1,1
2,5
3,6 
second iteration
1,1
2,5
3,3
.... and so on

Comment: Do you mean 1,3 2,7 3,3 for the second iteration?

Comment: what is the pattern that governs hat you want to print. explain your question properly.

Comment: Don't -1 a guy just because he didn't express his problem properly. It happens to all of us, and it's not lazyness here. @Abudullah: I don't get the combination you want, give more details, and check you didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you actually want...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you're trying to do is retrieve every unique set of three key,value pairs:

```
from itertools import permutations
# define dictList
# define numkeys to be the number of keys in dictList
# define maxLen to be the number of items in each dict value
perms = permutations(range(maxLen),numKeys)
for p in perms:
    i = 1     # you're indexing your dictionary from 1, not 0
    while i <= numKeys:
        myfunction(i,dictList[i][p[i-1]])   # ...which is why this is awkward
        i += 1
```

Comment: This will raise an IndexError based on OP's list.

Comment: No, I haven't run it but I just assumed that it would since you hadn't defined the length of `max` anywhere :) My english is teh sucks and my previous comment should have been worded differently.

Comment: I said "assuming you know that each list in the dictionary has length `max`." This means that you set `max` to the length of the lists.

Comment: True, it was sloppy of me, sorry! :)

Comment: I am sorry. I tried to explain the combinations properly. But stackoverflow restricted me to go for more details. Actually the combinations will be:

Comment: ist iter: 1,1 2,5 3,6 1,1 2,5 3,3..........
2nd iter: 1,1 2,7 3,6 1,1 2,7 3,3.......
ith-iter 1,3 2,5 3,6 1,3 2,5 3,3....
and so on...

Comment: Why do you have two values for each key in each iteration?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the possible combinations of values?

Comment: I need 2 value in each iteration because I will use (key, value) combination in a function like f(key, value). Yes, I am trying to get all possible combinations

Comment: Yeah, but you have 3 keys in your dictionary, yet your iterations each have 12 values: 2 copies of each key and 6 values. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: yaaaaah Guys, thanks for help and comments. I got it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Like it has been said, It seems you wrongly explained your problem.
But I guess you want something like :

> [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 3), (2, 7), (3, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 5), (1, 8), (2, 8), (3, 7)]

I will try to use `zip`. For example, zip on your values will associate all first items, all second items, etc.

**WARNING : it will only work if your lists have the same length !!!
(else you can import `itertools.izip_longest` to replace zip, the extra index will return None)**

```
>>> zip(*dictList.values())
[(1, 5, 6), (3, 7, 3), (4, 2, 5), (8, 8, 7)]
```

So the following code :

```
for t in zip(*dictList.values()):
...    for i, k in enumerate(dictList.keys()):
...       print k, t[i]
```

Will print :

```
1 1
2 5
3 6
1 3
2 7
3 3
1 4
2 2
3 5
1 8
2 8
3 7
```

There is a way to do it in one line :

```
>>> reduce(lambda cumul, v:cumul + list(zip(dictList.keys(), v)), zip(*dictList.values()), [])
[(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 6), (1, 3), (2, 7), (3, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (3, 5), (1, 8), (2, 8), (3, 7)]
```

Yes I know, **it's not really readable**, but I found it funny to try to do this kind of thing in one-line xD
Take your time to understand what is happening before using it.

Hope it helps,
Have a nice day.

Comment: This solution is slick, but I don't think it's what the OP wants; rather, the set of all possible combinations of values is needed.

Comment: oooo sorry, You answered it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    from itertools import product
    from itertools import izip_longest  # This is used to deal with variable length of lists

    dictList = {1:[1,3,4,8], 2:[5,7,2,8], 3:[6,3,5,7,8]}

    dict1 = [dict(izip_longest(dictList, v)) for v in product(*dictList.values())]

    for dict2 in dict1:
        for key, value in dict2.items():
            print key, value
```